# Adding Custom Point on the X axis- Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have the following project and only missing piece that I could not able to figure out that to add 0 on the X axis. The interval is 2000, therefore it is skipping 0 in the middle of X axis, which is start point.

```
      xAxis: {
            min: -5000
            , axisCrossingValue: [-5000, 0],
             labels: {
                 template: kendo.template($("#labelTemplate").html())
                },
        }
        , yAxis: {
            reverse: true
            , labels: {
                format: "{0}"
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/37/

Comment: There is no step in the zero value, that is why it isn't showing.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, no matter what I have done so far. I could not able to locate 0 value in the middle.

Comment: Idk how to do it as well, this part of the charts sucks...

Comment: it always forces me to have interval 2000.

Comment: Did you tried the `step` property?

Comment: I added `{step:1000}` property but nothing worked  in the x axis--> label. http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/38/

Comment: I had some tries but with no luck. i'm sry I'm afriad I can help you with this. I'm not good with those charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add majorUnit:1000 to the xAxis

```
 xAxis: {
        majorUnit:1000, //<-add here
        min: -5000 
        , axisCrossingValue: [-5000, 0],
         labels: {
             template: kendo.template($("#labelTemplate").html())
            },
    }
    , yAxis: {
        reverse: true
        , labels: {
            format: "{0}"
        }
    }
```